# Passing Values from html table to another html/js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is populated from a SQL Query. I want to let users to click on any row and load another html file or replace the current html view that should run another sql query based on the nth column value the user clicked on so it should populate the page. I'm stuck at transferring the value on click

```
var arr1 = [''];
var arr2 = [''];
var arr3 = [''];
var arr4 = [''];

function loadNames() {
var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
dbConn.connect().then(function () {
    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
    request.query("SQL QUERY").then(function (recordSet) {
        for (var i = 0; i < recordSet.recordsets[0].length; i++) {
            arr1.push(recordSet.recordset[i].col1);
            arr2.push(recordSet.recordset[i].col2);
            arr3.push(recordSet.recordset[i].col3);
            arr4.push(recordSet.recordset[i].col4);
        }
        $('#table').find('thead tr').append('<th>colName1</th>')
        $('#table').find('thead tr').append('<th>colName2</th>')
        $('#table').find('thead tr').append('<th>colName3</th>')
        $('#table').find('thead tr').append('<th>colName4</th>')
        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            $('#table').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ arr1[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr2[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr3[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr4[i] +'</td></tr>')
        }
        dbConn.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        dbConn.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
}
```

This populates without an issue, and i know how to populate the other table if i can somehow pass the value which is going to be a WHERE clause in SQL Query

UPDATE:

lets assume user clicked on 9th row, upon click it should display another html file and pass arr1[8]'s text value so i can use it on another sql query or in the same html file i need remove all table data, re-run the sql query and populate the table again. I just don't know how to pass that data

Comment: Do you want to know how to listen to the `onClick` Event? What have you tried? What is the exact problem? I don't even see an actual question in your post. Could you please update the question and add a little more information :)

Comment: Even simpler than `onclick`: use a good ol' anchor and set the URL parameters to it while rendering the first table. No guessing of row numbers or JS required…

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in getting the row index on click, you can simply change your row-adding code to register an onClick handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    $('#table').find('tbody').append('<tr onclick="getRow(this);"><td>'+ arr1[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr2[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr3[i] +'</td>'+'<td>'+ arr4[i] +'</td></tr>')
}
```

And also add the specified function:

```
function getRow(element) {
    // handle the data and refresh in doStuff
    doStuff(arr1[element.rowIndex]);
}
```

If you want to get the column and row, you need to to add a this function to the `td`-elements:

```
function getColumnAndRow(element) {
    // handle the data and refresh in doStuff
    // doStuff(row, column)
    doStuff(element.parentNode.rowIndex, element.cellIndex);
}
```